# Is there a way to create a virtual machine that runs android OS?

Tags: virtualbox, android, virtualization, ubuntu-for-android

I have been using the oracle VM, but I'll need to use a tablet soon at work. Therefore, I need to start experimenting with the android OS now. Is there a way to download the latest android OS and install it as a virtual machine in Ubuntu?

Comment: I think that this [Tutorial](http://www.whalesonggames.com/forums/showwiki.php?title=Technical+Tutorials:Virtualbox+Tutorial:+Creating+your+own+Android+virtual+machine+from+scratch) would be a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Here is how:

http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

and To install Virtualbox On Ubuntu Enter This In Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Enjoy and if this answered your question Click Answered And give me a small vote :P

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also: Please don't ask for reputation (through accepts and votes). Remind the asker to accept and vote, don't beg.

Comment: IM NOT im just saying ....

Comment: No, you're not "jsut saying". What you are saying is, literally, "give me a small vote".

Answer (score 0):

You can also download Androdi SDK, where there are a emulator in which you also can run Andorid machines.
http://developer.android.com/tools/workflow/index.html

And if you want to run ARM CPU, the software QEMU can also emulate a phone or tablet and run under Ubuntu.  But I guess that Google uses QEMU to emulate their Android devices would be easier.

But this are an emulation of ARM CPU on your machine, that propbalbly doesn't use ARM CPU.  Which mean it would be slower than running a Android in VirtualBox.