# Create a sort of snapchat

Tags: permissions

Maybe what I'm trying to do is not really legal but it's for my boyfriend, I just would like to send him pictures in the snapchat way. It means that I would impose a picture on his screen for a while without message to open before and without closing/deleting any work he could be doing.

We both have ubuntu and I don't know other places to get answers so if you also have ideas for my research, I take every kind of help...

Feel free to improve my request :)

Comment: You might be able to create a Virtual Machine to run android with Snapchat, like in the steps from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/290845/how-to-run-an-android-emulator-in-ubuntu-13-04) or [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307805/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-virtual-machine-that-runs-android-os) - I might get around to doing something like that so I can check  without having to connect my phone to wifi....

Comment: Everything is legal if you both agree (unless one of you is under 16 years old and the other isnt...)

Comment: @MrVaykadji - in which country? Anyway, It is legal, not much you could do that would be illegal - unless you ported SnapChat to Ubuntu... *(can't be bothered... yet)*

Comment: @Wilf Ok, I get the idea but it means that I'm gonna use the real Snapchat app and I will have to install it also on his pc and there's no more surprise... Am I wrong?

Comment: Hmmm... probably not wrong :-) - if you have a webserver and automate it, you could probably do something simple that would send him link that would display the picture for 10 seconds and remove/hide it.... sort of like Snapchat.

Comment: Oh you mean you don't have physical access to his computer ? Well that's gonna be almost impossible... (ps: @Wilf in Europe I think 16 is the sexual majority, not sure though, but it is at least discussed by the court before it's called pedophilia)

Comment: @MrVaykadji - the legal thing is probably more to do with accessing other computers... dunno.

Comment: I did not get she was asking to hack his boyfriend computer over the Internet... Well, that's illegal only if he goes to justice, I think (I think I could tell my sister "i'll kill you" and it would only be an issue if she sues me, am I right?)

Comment: I don't have a webserver and I don't like the idea of the link because that would be a surprise only the first time, then he will guess what it is.

Comment: I have and don't have physical access to his computer, we don't live together so it's when we see each other.

Comment: Yes what i had in mind was more like hacking his computer to impose  a picture for a while.

Comment: It would be simpler, less dodgy, and more likely to work, in my mind, to do the webserver based thing...

Comment: You might be able to you something like Dropbox actually... A simple page uploaded so that it would use javascript to show & hide the picture...